# PDPSharp chart location and background

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

How can I get x,y location of graph wher X and Y Axis starts (x,y location of point 0,0 in line chart)? This location is changable depending on text values on Y Axis probably.

Image is for illustrative purpose only.

[image]

How can I change the background color (currently is linear blue) of chart (I use PDFsharp NuGet package)?

Sample code:

```
ChartFrame chartFrame = new ChartFrame();
chartFrame.Location = new XPoint(xOffset, yLoc);
double chartHeight = Math.Min(250, (page.Height - yLoc - 10));
chartFrame.Size = new XSize((page.Width - (xOffset * 2)), chartHeight);

Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.Line);
//chart.PlotArea.FillFormat.Color = XColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255); //plot background???

Series series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
series.ChartType = ChartType.Line;
series.MarkerStyle = PdfSharp.Charting.MarkerStyle.None;
series.Name = "Horizontal"; //Series 1
series.MarkerBackgroundColor = XColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255); //blue
series.MarkerSize = 1;
series.Add(line1);

series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
series.ChartType = ChartType.Line;
series.MarkerStyle = PdfSharp.Charting.MarkerStyle.None;
series.Name = "Vertical"; //Series 2
series.MarkerBackgroundColor = XColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 170, 0); //green
series.MarkerSize = 1;
series.Add(line2);

series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
series.ChartType = ChartType.Line;
series.MarkerStyle = PdfSharp.Charting.MarkerStyle.None;
series.Name = "3D position"; //Series 3
series.MarkerBackgroundColor = XColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0); //red
series.MarkerSize = 1;
series.Add(line3);

chart.XAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
chart.XAxis.Title.Caption = "No. Events"; //X-Axis

chart.YAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
chart.YAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
double yOffset = ((maxYscale - minYscale) / 6);
if (yOffset < 0.01f)
    yOffset = 0.01f;
chart.YAxis.MinimumScale = 0;
chart.YAxis.MaximumScale = Math.Round(Math.Round((maxYscale + yOffset), 3), 2);
double jump = Math.Round(yOffset, 2);
if (jump < 0.01f)
    jump = 0.01f;
chart.YAxis.MajorTick = jump;
chart.YAxis.TickLabels.Format = "#0.00";
//chart.YAxis.HasMinorGridlines = true;
chart.YAxis.Title.Caption = "[m]"; //Y-Axis
chart.YAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;

chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Color = XColors.DarkGray;
chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Width = 1;
chart.PlotArea.LineFormat.Visible = true;

chart.Legend.Docking = DockingType.Bottom;
chart.Legend.LineFormat.Visible = true;

XSeries xseries = chart.XValues.AddXSeries();
xseries.Add(eventLine);

chartFrame.Add(chart);
chartFrame.Draw(gfx);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re:for X,Y location:
I made quick check for text length on YAxis and then according to that calculate new X,Y position.
Re: Background color:
These colours are hard-coded in the ChartFrame class (Draw method). So the nugget package for PDFSharp is not good you need to download the library source code.
Search for "XColor.FromArgb(0xFFD0DEEF)" and update the source code as needed.